# Change LineString type of Osm2Po edge and vertex file

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

Is it possible to change the linestring type from 2 to 3 dimensions in osm2po, and if so, how? Currently the generated table column looks like this: **geom_way geometry(LineString,4326),** but I would much rather like to have *geom_way geometry(LineStringZ,4326),*

Answer (score 1):

Here is an original but older Code of the PgRoutingWriter.

https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting-contrib/blob/master/plugin-osm2po/PgRoutingWriter.java

Comment: Hey Carsten, thanks for the hint and btw thanks for your great library, very much appreciated! But what am I supposed to do with the source code?

Comment: osm2po provides a plugin mechanism. Use the code as template. The crucial part is in line 129 : `String geom_way = GeomConverter.latLons2LineWkbHex(waySegment.getNodes(), true);` Replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: and ... of course, you'll need some basic Java knowledge